# Why would a validation rule change not appear in the Audit log?

Tags: validation-rule, setup-audit-log

We have a validation rule that says it was last updated on day X by a user.
However, in the audit log, there are no entries for this VR on that day, nor the user was active on that day.

Any ideas what actions can happen to a VR, but not be tracked in Audit Log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_monitorsetup.htm&type=5) doesn't get specific and just says changes to validation rules are tracked.

However, in a quick test I confirmed the following changes to the Validation Rule were shown in the Setup Audit Trail

- Name updates
- Error Condition formula updates
- Error Message
- Error Location
- Active

In terms of your question, **only one change was not tracked**:

- Description

I would assume that is the scenario you're looking at since it doesn't appear in the Audit log.